# check string is in certain format in php

Tags: php

I want to check whether the string is in the following format in php,

```
DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM: Any string message 1, may contain any special character
```

above syntax should be matched with the incoming string
example:

```
 12/01/2015, 10:15: Happy New Year 2015
```

How to check this format in php?

Comment: Must the first part it be a valid Date/Time as well or just digits?

Comment: just digits but should be in specified format, i'm happy if u specify for valid Date/Time also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "12/01/2015, 10:15: Happy New Year 2015";

if(preg_match('/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\,\ \d{2}:\d{2}:.*/', $string)) {
        echo "$string passed check.";
}
```

Now if you want to ensure that the first part is a valid DateTime format, you can do that too, but it wasn't clear from your request.

**Edit**: Based on your followup, you could do something like this:

```
$string = "12/01/2015, 10:15: Happy New Year 2015";

function validate($string)
{
        if(preg_match('/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\,\ \d{2}:\d{2}:.*/', $string)) {
                $split = preg_split('/:\ /', $string);
                $date = str_replace(', ', ':', $split[0]);
                $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y:H:i', $date);
                return $d && $d->format('m/d/Y:H:i') == $date;
        }
        return false;
}

var_dump(validate($string));
```

It just extracts the date section, and verifies that it's a valid DateTime object.  I left the `preg_match()` in because it will ensure that the data coming in is appropriate for the Date validation.